# Export the query with the reports?

Tags: force.com, reporting

I recieved this question from a user today, and in all fairness I see her point. I don't think there's a way to do this, but I 'd like to go back to her with something meaningful, aside from take a screen shot of the qurey and put it in onenote..

Is there a way in SFDC to pull in your filters of your report when exporting? If we can pull in the filters it makes for an easier way to duplicate the report. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The printable view option includes the filters:

[image]