# How to export / import the query for a report?

Tags: salesforcedx, reporting

I'm looking for a way to export a report query from one org and import into other orgs without re-typing it. Is that possible?

I did find [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24842/export-the-query-with-the-reports) old answer which would partially help but I'm wondering whether there might be a way via SFDX with an XML file, for instance.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the report using vscode, then deploying it?

Comment: No, but that is the type of thing I was hoping for - can you give me any pointers @(Nick C) ? (Internet examples, documentation, Trailhead etc for similar scenarios?)

Comment: You can search for "VS Code Salesforce" for installation and general usage notes.  Then search further for deploy + retrieve metadata with vs code and you should be able to do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using workbench

1. Create an outbound Changeset (Setup->Quick Find->Outbound
   Changesets)
2. Click Add -> Select Component Type Report, Select
   Report and click Add To Changeset
3. Now open [workbench][1] and authenticate to your source org
4. Select migration->Retrieve from top menu Provide Package Name as the Changeset Name you created, check Single Package checkbox as true and click next.
5. once next page loads, download the metadata Zip file
6. Login to Target org in an incognito window and open workbench.
7. Select migration->Deploy from top menu
8. Choose the Zip file retrieved in step 5 and check Single Package checkbox as true and click next.
9. Click Deploy to deploy the report

NB: The related objects and dependency should be present in target org or you need to add this also

If you have VS code installed and project set up already, You can connect to the source org, retrieve the report, change the default org to target org and deploy the same report in target org.
[1]: https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Comment: Thank you @Vivek , I'll give that a try.

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it helped 